# How to create release on feature branch

Tags: git, github

We're using the rebase option (exclusively) to merge feature branches into the master branch and I don't know how to prepare releases.

I'd like to prepare everything on a feature branch (release notes, changelog, tag). However, this does not really work as the tag is on the commit on the branch, which is not the one that shows up on the master branch once it is merged.

I guess this is a common pattern, hence a common problem. How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can click the "Save Draft" button instead of "Publish Release". A tag will be created on master only when the release is effectively published

[image]

Comment: That would work, I guess. I'm using npm and I could bump the version with `npm version ... --no-git-tag-version`.